# Running parallel markdowns in Concordion

Tags: java, concordion

Is there a posibility to run few concordion markdowns in parallel
I have something like:

1. Test1
2. Test2

and Test2.md is started after Test1.md is finished

Can I run Test2.md in the same time as Test1.md?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [parallel run extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion-parallel-run-extension) provides this capability.

You'll need to create a "parent" specification which uses the run command to call Test1.md and Test2.md. Then add the parallel run extension to the parent fixture.